# Facebook ads not showing already logined in with a Facebook account

Tags: java, android, facebook, ads

Can't show Facebook ads. My Facebook ads placement id status is "Requesting ads" shows. and also it has fully green dot display. I have done perfect code in my code area. If i am change my ads placement is as "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID" then ads will shows and whenever i changed my placement id then ads doesn't shows. I also login in my device Facebook app with same Facebook account which is business account.
[image]

Comment: on adLoadfailed you will get the error code and error message. catch that error code and message and google it

Comment: Thanks dude. Is this necessary the app is Live? After is it shows? @MahendraGohil

Comment: no it's not necessary whether app is live or not...

Answer (score 0):

on adload failed you get the error code and error message
[here is error description with error code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing/#errors) and also run your Signed APK

```
public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
    // Ad error callback
    Log.e(TAG, "Ad failed to load: " + adError.getErrorCode());
    Log.e(TAG, "Ad failed to load: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
}
```